# How to solve "E405: Remote package tasks should have a retry" in Ansible?

Tags: ansible

> [E405](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-lint/blob/master/docs/docsite/rst/rules/default_rules.rst) v4.0.0   Remote package tasks should have a retry    Package
>   operations are unreliable as they require network communication and
>   the availability of remote servers. To mitigate the potential
>   problems, retries should be used via register: my_result and until:
>   my_result | success

This shows up when running `ansible-lint` as the following error:

```
[405] Remote package tasks should have a retry
plays/sample.yml:31
Task/Handler: Install list of packages
```

Given the sample code:

```
- name: Install list of packages
  apt:
    name: [jq, vim, curl, unzip, dnsutils]
    state: present
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`ansible-lint` warning `405` can be quite irritating as in certain cases, i.e. when running locally retrying is very unlikely to make any difference.  Actually resolving it is normally simply a case of adding the following:

```
register: task_result
until: task_result is success
retries: 10
delay: 2
```

When this is added to task Ansible will retry ten times with a delay of two seconds between each retry until the `returncode` is `0`.

Comment: Seems like an extremely nitpicky rule to me... there are some cases where this would be nice to have, but in the real world I think I've seen this on package-related tasks maybe < 1% of the time. Which is why I've opened [405 Remote package tasks should have a retry - too nitpicky?](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-lint/issues/456)

Comment: I don’t think it’s too nit picky - I find more often than not I add extra lines just to appease Ansible-lint rather than to deliver value, this seems wrong.  Retry by default seems sensible.

Comment: 1% is a huge numer if you the numeber operations done during a deployment. Even 1/1000 would be high enough to request a retry logic. Do not forget the multiplication factor and the cost of a failure.

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install --upgrade ansible-lint>=4.1.0
```

Rule 405 has been dropped following the discussion in https://github.com/ansible/ansible-lint/issues/456